# Replicate Remote DB Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, replication, pid

I´m following this tutorial (http://www.linux-party.com/42-mysql/8628-como-replicar-una-de-base-de-datos-de-mysql-2-de-2)..

When I configure slave (my.cnf) with this parameters:

```
server-id=2
master-host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
master-user=root
master-password=xxxxxxxxx
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=db_mirror
```

And restart mysql, I get the following error:

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file 
(/var/lib/mysql/xxxxxxxxx.com.pid)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: does the directory /var/lib/mysql exist and does mysql run under a user id that has write access to that locatoin?

Comment: Yes, user has full privilegies and the directory also exists

Comment: This is the error log


171204 18:53:34 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
171204 18:53:34 [Note]   - '*' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
171204 18:53:34 [Note]   - '*' resolves to '::';
171204 18:53:34 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
171204 18:53:34 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=sd-941934-l-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File my.cnf was bad configurated....